# OSX Big Sur 11.2.3 milliseconds timestamp appears as all zeroes

Tags: macos, time, settings

I have an app that I would like to see very specific timestamps of operations. It uses the Short time format of my computer, which I changed in.

Settings>Language And Region>Advanced>Times

This worked very well, and allowed me to add seconds to the timestamps in my app. However, when it comes to milliseconds, something goes wrong. It displays the milliseconds portion as all zeroes. Regardless of how many digits I set the milliseconds option to in Settings>Language And Region>Advanced>Times, they all always appear as zeroes in practice.

I am using macOS Big Sur version 11.2.3. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a Date and a DateFormatter?

Comment: Like this? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter No I'm not doing anything like that. I'm just changing settings in System Preferences Settings>Language And Region>Advanced>Times to include seconds and milliseconds

Comment: What code are you using to get your time stamps?

Comment: Here's what it looks like to me.    7:08 AM + 09.00seconds                             
Here' swhat it looks like when I copy-> paste it h:mma +ss.SS'seconds'

Comment: I’m sorry, but I don’t know.

Comment: I appreciate you giving it a shot. Let me know if you find anything that might help!